# how to force a user to select a value other than the 'select'?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#d1").change(function() {

            alert("Handler for .change() called.");
            $("#TextBox2").val($("#d1").val());
            $("#d2").css('visibility', 'visible');
            if ($("#d1").val() = 'Select') {
                alert('please select a valid value');
                //$("#d1").focus();
            }
        });
   <select name="ctl03" id="d1">
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Medium-Low">Medium-Low</option>
        <option value="Medium-High">Medium-High</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>

    </select>
```

i want that user should select a value.if user selects the first option i.e.(select)
than an alert should be generated and the control should go back to dropdownlist

Comment: What part is not working? Looks like you already have something in place to notify the user if he/she selects `Select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disable` that option!

```
<option value="Select" disabled selected>Select</option>
```

The `select` will default to this option, but once you click it you MUST select something

Comment: how to do that in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

it should be `==` instead of `=`

```
if ($("#d1").val() == 'Select') {
```

Comment: doing this wil genrate a message but still user can move forward without selecting a value

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select name="ctl03" id="d1" onchange="changed(this.value);">
```

JS:

```
function changed(d) {
        if (d == 'Select' && d !== '') {
            alert('Please select a valid value!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: doing this wil genrate a message but still user can move forward without selecting a value

Comment: move forward to what? If you got other form elements after the select field you should disable them and enable them with $('#next_element').prop('disabled', 'false'); You could also place an overlay over the next elements with an higher z-index and opacity and after the right select option is clicked you can set it to the default values

Answer (score 0):

if ($("#d1").val() = 'Select')
  this statement replace
 if ($("#d1").val() == 'Select')

Comment: doing this wil genrate a message but still user can move forward without selecting a value

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of tymeJV and sudars answers. This way if the user submits and does not click the drop down you are still covered in code.

```
<option value="Select" disabled selected>Select</option>
```

AND

```
if ($("#d1").val() == 'Select') {
```

Note:
There are validation plugins you can use as well. That could compartmentalize your operation and validation code

Comment: <option value="Select" disabled selected>Select</option> how to do that in asp